# minimum difficulty for Ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum

What is the lowest possible difficulty that can be set in genesis file so the first block starts with minimal difficulty and then grows slowly to reach the regular >100k difficulty levels ?

I have done some tests , and if I set the difficulty to 1,2, 16 or 32 the difficulty doesn't grow. It stays constant, and I have proofs of that.

This is how I do it:

```
[niko@localhost difeth]$ cat genesis.json 
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 444,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "0x20",
    "gasLimit": "2100000",
    "alloc": {
    }
}
[niko@localhost difeth]$ 
[niko@localhost difeth]$ g --datadir /home/niko/saved-niko-home/difeth init ./genesis.json 
[niko@localhost difeth]$ g --datadir /home/niko/saved-niko-home/difeth --networkid 444 console
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.2-unstable-ad444752/linux-amd64/go1.8.3
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> personal.newAccount()
Passphrase: 
Repeat passphrase: 
"0xc2b3b2f2ce7945cd60f3c7c30a4b02565c4786cf"
> miner.start(1)
INFO [10-16|17:17:52] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [10-16|17:17:52] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [10-16|17:17:52] Starting mining operation 
null
> INFO [10-16|17:17:52] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=332.1µs
INFO [10-16|17:17:52] Successfully sealed new block            number=1 hash=5bdbe9…387386
INFO [10-16|17:17:52]  mined potential block                  number=1 hash=5bdbe9…387386
INFO [10-16|17:17:52] Commit new mining work                   number=2 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=243.157µs
INFO [10-16|17:17:52] Successfully sealed new block            number=2 hash=52b61f…66617b
INFO [10-16|17:17:52]  mined potential block                  number=2 hash=52b61f…66617b
.....
```

On another console I do:

```
[niko@localhost difeth]$ g --datadir /home/niko/saved-niko-home/difeth attach ipc:/home/niko/saved-niko-home/difeth/geth.ipc
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.7.2-unstable-ad444752/linux-amd64/go1.8.3
coinbase: 0xc2b3b2f2ce7945cd60f3c7c30a4b02565c4786cf
at block: 8 (Mon, 16 Oct 2017 17:17:59 CDT)
 datadir: /home/niko/saved-niko-home/difeth
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> loadScript("/home/niko/saved-niko-home/myeth/snippets/dumpdiff.js");
true
> dumpDiff()
32  0   0
32  1508192272  1508192272
32  1508192273  1
32  1508192274  1
32  1508192275  1
32  1508192276  1
32  1508192277  1
32  1508192278  1
32  1508192279  1
32  1508192280  1
32  1508192281  1
32  1508192282  1
32  1508192283  1
32  1508192284  1
32  1508192285  1
32  1508192286  1
32  1508192287  1
32  1508192288  1
32  1508192289  1
32  1508192290  1
32  1508192291  1
32  1508192292  1
32  1508192293  1
undefined
> exit
```

Here the first column is the difficulty, the second is the timestamp, and the third is the time to create a block, in seconds. What I was expecting is that the first column had the difficulty like 32,40,54,67,89,122... and so on, but not constant 32.

This is how dumpdiff() is defined:

```
[niko@localhost snippets]$ cat dumpdiff.js 
function dumpDiff() {
    var i,end;
    var block;

    end=web3.eth.blockNumber;
    var prev_ts=0;
    var seconds;
    for (i=0;i<end;i++) {
        block=web3.eth.getBlock(i,true);
        seconds=block.timestamp-prev_ts
        console.log(block.difficulty+"\t"+block.timestamp+"\t"+seconds);
        prev_ts=block.timestamp;
    }
}
[niko@localhost snippets]$
```

Now, I had to modify params/protocol_params.go to set MinimumDifficulty to 2 because it didn't work with lower difficulties than 131072, but I am not sure if this is still relevant with latest sources.

Comment: It is not the same but to generate blocks as quickly as possible we changed [`CalcDifficulty`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/v1.7.2/consensus/ethash/consensus.go#L286) to always return 1. 
```
func CalcDifficulty(config *params.ChainConfig, time uint64, parent *types.Header) *big.Int {
   return big.NewInt(1)
}
```, also have to remove some other warnings.

Comment: @Ismael yes, I know, I changed it removing the time bomb. I guess I will have to look at difficulty algorithm , some math is wrong there with low numbers, it must be rising always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with trial and error, I found a number of 2250. If lower numbers are used the difficulty can freeze at constant rate below 2050.

```
> dumpDiff()
2250    0   0
2151    1508233789  1508233789
2152    1508233790  1
2153    1508233791  1
2154    1508233792  1
2155    1508233793  1
2156    1508233794  1
2157    1508233795  1
2158    1508233796  1
2159    1508233797  1
2160    1508233798  1
2161    1508233799  1
2162    1508233800  1
2163    1508233801  1
2164    1508233802  1
2165    1508233803  1
2166    1508233804  1
2167    1508233805  1
2168    1508233806  1
2169    1508233807  1
2170    1508233808  1
2171    1508233809  1
2172    1508233810  1
2173    1508233811  1
2174    1508233812  1
2175    1508233813  1
2176    1508233814  1
2177    1508233815  1
2178    1508233816  1
2179    1508233817  1
2180    1508233818  1
2181    1508233819  1
2182    1508233820  1
2183    1508233821  1
2184    1508233822  1
2185    1508233823  1
2186    1508233824  1
2187    1508233825  1
2188    1508233826  1
2189    1508233827  1
```

Now it is constantly rising.

Comment: This is probably due to the difficultbounddivisor being 2048. I haven't looked at this further though.

Comment: @T9b , definitely it is. Thanks for pointing it out!